# jQuery next() not working with live()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

When I try and use the jQuery `next()` method it doesn't work with `live()`.

First off, here is my code:

```
$(".toggle_button").live('click', function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html() == '-' ? '+' : '-');
    $(this).next(".info_section").toggle(400);
});
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div class='section_toggle_container'>
    <div class='toggle_button'>-</div>
    <strong>Driver Information:</strong>
</div>
<div class='info_section'>
    info here
</div>
```

Would the problem maybe lie in the fact that `.toggle_button` is nested, making `.info_section` unreachable?

The second line works great, because it's modifying the element given the `live()` event. The third line, however, is where the problem's at. This is because it's using `next()`.

Can anyone help me with a solution for my `next()` problem?

Comment: You will need to show the HTML this is applying to I think.  Is it possible that there is no `.info_section` following the `.toggle_button` element?  Or are you destroying `this` with the `.html()` call in the line above?  Try using `.text()` instead.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? **How does your HTML look like?** `next()` will only return an element **if and only if** the next sibling of `this` has class `info_section`. It does **not** return the next sibling with class `info_section`.

Comment: @Orbling: `html` only affects the content, not the element itself.

Comment: Post your actual code, I have no idea what your problem is. I can get it working no problem: http://jsfiddle.net/jWR6A/ But all I've done is take a random guess at whatever the heck it is you want to do. Post the HTML. Or better describe what .next isn't doing, because it's doing exactly what the docs say it should do.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Good point, though it would still be better to use `.text()` given the changes being made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the HTML should't your statement:

```
$(this).next(".info_section").toggle(400);
```

be:

```
$(this).parent().next(".info_section").toggle(400);
```

Answer (score 1):

While you have the working answer, I wanted to leave a suggestion about your toggling of the `-` and `+`, I'd suggest using `text()` instead of HTML, and using the inherent `text` (for `text()`, `html` for `html()`):

```
$(".toggle_button").live('click', function() {
    $(this).text(function(index,text) {
        return text == '-' ? '+' : '-';
    });
    $(this).parent().next(".info_section").toggle(400);
});
```

And, further, I'd suggest caching your `$(this)`, if you're calling it more than once it's worthwhile using caching to prevent having to recreate it subsequently, leading to:

```
$(".toggle_button").live('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text(function(index,text) {
        return text == '-' ? '+' : '-';
    });
    $this.parent().next(".info_section").toggle(400);
});
```

Of course, if you're using a version of jQuery greater than, or including, 1.7, then you should be using the `on()` method, rather than the (since jQuery 1.7) deprecated `live()`, which would give:

```
$(".toggle_button").on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text(function(index,text) {
        return text == '-' ? '+' : '-';
    });
    $this.parent().next(".info_section").toggle(400);
});
```

This really is just advice, though, unfortunately posted as an answer to prevent incomprehensible code being pasted into a comment.

References:

- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
- [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).